# Does default scope get added on to other scopes in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

**Are the `order` queries in the following two scopes not needed because of the default?**

```
scope :paid, where('is_paid_merchant = true').order('weekly_clicks DESC')
scope :unpaid, where('is_paid_merchant = false').order('weekly_clicks DESC')
default_scope order('weekly_clicks DESC')
```

**If the default scope is indeed added onto all other scopes, what's the precedence** of that order? Is it the first one applied or the last one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default scope is the first one applied. You can override it with other scopes, or use `unscoped` in order to avoid it completely. Personally, I find default scopes very bad practice since they make the code harder to understand.